# No Cache in Facebook (Title and Image)

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, caching, sdk

Hello I'm trying a page not available in the Facebook cache.

I have, for example, an example
D-i-s-n-e-y.com

I tried using https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/article/ but it does not work.

Someone got this solution

Comment: Please clarify as to what you're asking – the question isn't very clear.

Comment: Pretty sure he is asking about the _"same URL, different thumbnail each time it is posted"_ nonsense that is going around lately. I’d expect Facebook to take measures against that soon anyway.

Comment: Exactly, I would like to know what tags are being used or facebook sdk that is not leaving facebook cached images.

Last url deals with this, in fact, at that moment, in a comment, on facebook it carries a different title and image.

This is the one that wants to share a url and always change the title and image.

I gave an example:

http://novo.dgportas.com.br/random/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found some other examples.

http://c-o-m-i-d-a.com/

http://143xp.com/

When they are shared without facebook they generate tumb and different titles in each comment.

Someone has been able to identify this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Other links I found that do the same when shared.

http://b-i-c-h-o.com

https://www.dopl3r.com/

I already used it:

```
        $(function () {

            $.post('https://graph.facebook.com',
                    {
                        id: 'http://novo.dgportas.com.br/random/',
                        scrape: true
                    },
                    function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    }
            );
        });
```

However whenever shared the same tag title and image is on facebook, do not link the cache.